# Tkinter create clear button to clear various textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have around 40 textboxes named from d1 to d40.

Currently I have created a Clear Button with 40 lines, each line stating the textbox number (eg: "d1.delete(0, END)" to clear the textbox).

I know there should be a smarter way... but I tried many times and failed.

Below please find extract of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


win = Tk()
win.wm_title("Testing")
win.wm_geometry("400x400+10+30")

v = StringVar()
v.set('abcd')
d1 = Entry(win, text=v)
d1.place(x=10, y=10, height=30, width=400)

s = StringVar()
s.set('abc22222222')
d2 = Entry(win, text=s)  
d2.place(x=10, y=50, height=30, width=400)

t = StringVar()
t.set('abc22sdfefe222222')
d3 = Entry(win, text=t)  
d3.place(x=10, y=90, height=30, width=400)

def clearcomm():
    n = 0
    for i in range(3):
        n +=1
        'd{}.delete(0, END)'.format(n)

Button(win, text='Clear', command=clearcomm, height=1, width=6, font=("arial", 7, "bold"), fg="white", bg="red").place(x=10, y=150)        
             
mainloop()
```

then I also tried:

```
clearlist = []
n = 0

for i in range(3):
    n +=1
    command = 'd{}.delete(0, END)'.format(n)
    clearlist.append(command)
    
n = 0
def clearcomm():
    for list in clearlist:
        return
```

but this one no response...so I do not know how to do it. Very grateful if you can give some advise.

Comment: You can use a list to store the references of the `Entry` widgets and then you can loop through the list to clear the content of the entries.

Comment: Thx for reply....I did something like:
clearlist = []
n = 0

for i in range(3):
    n +=1
    command = 'd{}.delete(0, END)'.format(n)
    clearlist.append(command)
    
n = 0
def clearcomm():
    for list in clearlist:
        return but no respose.....

Comment: You should have looped over a list of entries and done like `for item in entry_list:` and then `item.delete(0, 'end')`

Answer (score 0):

The smarter way you probably look for is a list of all textboxes you want to clear:

```
global textboxes
textboxes = []
global contents
contents = []

for y in [10,50,90]:
    v = StringVar()
    v.set('sometext')
    d1 = Entry(win, textvariable=v)
    d1.place(x=10, y=y, height=30, width=400)
    textboxes.append(d1)
    contents.append(v)
```

You then have two lists. One containing all entry widgets, the other containing all contents. You can manipulate both using for-loops to iterate over all objects:

```
def clearcomm():
    for c in contents:
         c.set('')
```

or

```
def clearcomm():
    for t in textboxes:
        t.delete(0,END)
```

Both should work since you use textvariables.

[EDIT: global statements moved uniformly to the front. Thanks for noting, Cool Cloud.]

Comment: You can remove `global textboxes` in the first example as its already globalized.

Answer (score 0):

This will clear all three(3) `Entry` widgets.

Change this:

```
def clearcomm():
    n = 0
    for i in range(3):
        n +=1
        'd{}.delete(0, END)'.format(n)
```

to:

```
def clearcomm():
    [widget.delete(0, tk.END) for widget in win.winfo_children() if isinstance(widget, tk.Entry)]
```

Also, you can for  40 textboxes by changing `if isinstance(widget, tk.Text)` # Entry to Text